# SQL DELETE Erroneously Emptied Entire Database Instead of One Table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let me say upfront that this was luckily in a testing environment, so no actual loss, but it is still a bug I want to understand.

So I am testing a new way of loading raw data into a system I work on, which stores its data in a PostgreSQL database. Since the method I am testing is now working the data is getting into the table. Rather than generating a new set of testing data, I figured I would just delete the fake entries from my testing environment and go again; To do this, I ran the below command in `psql`.

```sql
DELETE FROM unprocessed_data_table;
```

Now, my expectation was that this would simply delete the data in `unprocessed_data_table`. However, that table is the child of several other tables (its values are subject to Foreign Key Constraints) and after running the above `DELETE` command, I found the data for all of `unprocessed_data_table` parent tables had also been dropped from my database. Does anyone know why this might have happened?

To be clear, there are no tables that depend on `unprocessed_data_table`, it is its ascendent tables that were emptied. And the tables still exist, it was just that their contents was deleted.

Comment: My best guess would be that you have `ON DELETE CASCADE` set up for your foreign key constraints, so that deletes in your table are cascaded to the referenced tables.

Comment: Oh dear, is cascade two way? I thought it just meant that deletions on the parent table would delete child entries. Cause the erroneously deleted entries were parent entries.

Comment: It's one way - if your `OrderLine` table references the `Orders` table via a "on delete cascade" foreign key, then deleting a row from `Orders` will also delete all rows in `OrderLine` that reference that `Orders` entry - but not the other way around.

Comment: A FK `CASCADE` goes from parent to child. Sounds like you have triggers on `unprocessed_data_table` that deleted the other way.

Comment: It seems your claim is contradictory to experience. Please post a [mre] so the community can see what exactly is happening.